# Cannot get Delete Button to work on a datatables table

Tags: datatables, delete-row

I successfully created a todo list without any issues.  However, I tried to further adapt the app to also display a table of all the todos.

Everything works great except for the delete portion.

I now have 2x jQuery functions to listen for delete keypress (One for the list and one for the table):

```
// ============= Remove todo from the list and Database ============
$('.list').on('click', 'span', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  removeTodo($(this).parent());  // Remove todo from the list and 
  Database
})


// ============== Remove todo from the table and Database ==========
  $('tbody').on('click', '.btn-danger', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    table                         // remove row from table - Start
    .row($(this).parents('tr'))   // ...
    .remove()                     // ... 
    .draw()                       // remove row from table - End

    removeOnt($(this).parent());  // Remove from database -  HOWEVER, NOT WORKING
  })
```

Then I have the function that removes the todo:

```
function removeTodo(todo){
  var clickedId = todo.data('id');             // I know the problem with removing the data from the database when I call the function from the table jQuery call, doesn't work
  var deleteUrl = '/api/todos/' + clickedId; 
  $.ajax({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: deleteUrl
  })
  .then(function(data){
    todo.remove();
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
  })
}
```

The problem with the function to delete the entry from the database via the Table call, is because because "**var clickedId = todo.data('id');**" is "*undefined*".

The above mentioned **data('id')** from **todo.data('id')** gets defined the the "addTodo(todo){}" function as

```
var newTodo = $('<li class="task">'+todo.name +' <span>X</span></li>');
newTodo.data('id', todo._id);
```

This is code for the function to create the table row:

```
function addTodoRow(todo){
  table.row.add([
            todo.name,
            todo.created_date,
            "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>DELETE</button>"
  ]).draw();
  if(todo.completed){
    $('td').addClass('done');
  } 
}
```

My question is:  How do I define the equivalent of "**newTodo.data('id', todo._id);**" in the "**addTodoRow(todo)**"  function as we did for "**addTodo(todo)**"?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Stephan

Answer (score 0):

I checked your JS code for adding rows to the data table,

```
function addTodoRow(todo){
  // console.log(todo.name)
  table.row.add([
            todo.name,
            todo.created_date,
            'High',
            'MyName',
            "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>DELETE</button>"
  ]).draw();
  if(todo.completed){
    $('td').addClass('done');
  } 
}
```

Here are my suggestions,

-> Like you're passing the value for **todo.name, todo.created_date**.

-> Pass the value of your record is of the database. Like **todo.db_record_id**

-> and change the following in the button, the new JS for this will be

```
function addTodoRow(todo){
  // console.log(todo.name)
  table.row.add([
            todo.name,
            todo.created_date,
            'High',
            'MyName',
            "<button onclick='removeTodo(+todo.db_record_id+)' type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>DELETE</button>"
  ]).draw();
  if(todo.completed){
    $('td').addClass('done');
  } 
}
```

-> update the JS function to delete the record,

```
function removeTodo(todo_id){
  console.log(todo.name);
  var deleteUrl = '/api/todos/' + todo_id; 
  $.ajax({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: deleteUrl
  })
  .then(function(data){
    todo.remove();
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
  })
}
```

Try the above steps. Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thanks @Sunil,  appreciate you prompt response and willingness to assist.   The problem I am stuck wit is not removal of the row from Datatables but more with removal of the data from the MongoDB database.   I am trying to find a way to extract either the "_id" or another data value from the row to use in my DELETE request to the mongodb api.

Comment: I didn't work on MongoDB if you will add your code how you're filling the data in the Datatable (like using ajax, HTML using MongoDB data, etc). So might be I may help you.

Comment: Ok no problem.  I'll do one better.  I will add the full application to cloud 9 with open access.  You will have full access to the code and mongodb.
Will let you know once ready.

Comment: Here you go:

Access to the code:  https://ide.c9.io/asdutoit/todo-list-help
Access to the App:   https://todo-list-help-asdutoit.c9users.io

The Node server is currently running so you should be able to open the app and play.  If you make change just remember to stop the server and restart by issuing the following command in the console:

asdutoit:~/workspace/Todo App/todos_api (master) $ node index.js

Comment: Thanks @Sunil, 
I did as you proposed but get the following error:

app.js:70 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.  It seems to have a problem with this line of code:  "<button onclick="removeTodo(+todo.db_record_id+)" type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>DELETE</button>"

I have added the code to Cloud 9.  The JSLint also indicated there is a problem. 

I have made 2x screenshots that can be found here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vgiwmi4glcgdfl1/Screenshot%202018-05-24%2014.15.22.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/agh7yypvncjr8fo/Screenshot%202018-05-24%2014.13.04.png?dl=0

Comment: Sorry my mistake it will be like this with the single quote, "<button onclick='removeTodo(+todo.db_record_id+)' type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>DELETE</button>". before I added onclick="removeTodo(+todo.db_record_id+)"

Comment: I picked it up and amended but it still did not resolve the issue.  I did, however, find another slightly convoluted way to make it work.  I am not particularly proud of it and sure there must be another way.  Will post the answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around to find the value and call the delete function to successfully remove the row and mongodb record.

Code was adjusted as follow:

1. Another function was added:

```js
function removeTodo2(todo_id){
  var deleteUrl = '/api/todos/' + todo_id; 
  $.ajax({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: deleteUrl
  })
  .then(function(data){
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
  })
}
```

2. The jQuery listener has been updated to listen when clicking on the delete button and extract the required value from the row in order to pass it into the delete function (removeTodo2(todo_id)) to delete the mongodb record.  Phew, what a mouthful.

```js
//Remove todo from the table and Database
  $('tbody').on('click', '.btn-danger', function(e){
    var test = $(this).parents('tr');
    var test2 = test.find('td:eq(2)')[0].innerHTML;  // Find the mongodb record ID.  Note, for the purpose of this exercise the ID as been added to the row, but would not be done in reality. 
    e.stopPropagation();
    table                         // remove row from table - Start
    .row($(this).parents('tr'))   // ...
    .remove()                     // ... 
    .draw()                       // remove row from table - End
    removeTodo2(test2);  // Remove from database -  HOWEVER, NOT WORKING
  })
```

This worked for my purpose, but I don't think this is the right way of doing it.

Thanks for all the help @Sunil Dora